# Something confusing about "su -" and "su"

Tags: linux, shell, command

I am studying the Linux command line. But the book which I'm reading says that `su -l(-) username` is starting a new shell session and loading the environment of the user I want to change to, but `su` doesn't.

When I was root user, I entered the command `su testuser`, so I am testuser. But after that, I entered `echo "$USER"`, and it says `testuser`. It means that it loads testuser's environment, doesn't it? Is there something wrong?

And what does "starts a new shell session" mean exactly? Does shell have a mechanism like login, logout?

Comment: Just run 'env' instead of 'echo $USER'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**su** gives you root permissions but it does not change the PATH variable and current working directory. so you can't execute files in /usr/sbin folder.

**su-** changes the PATH too... and root's home becomes your current working directory. you become proper root and can execute all commands.